# php regex reading specific lines

Tags: php, regex, match

I have a problem. I'm trying to count number of a subtitle lines with php.
As you might know, a subtitle looks like this:

```
1
00:00:00,984 --> 00:00:03,503
All right, guys, let's get to it.

2
00:00:03,587 --> 00:00:04,821
What's that button?

3
00:00:04,872 --> 00:00:07,590
It's something designed
to help you get healthy.

4
00:00:07,658 --> 00:00:09,676
Just ignore it.

5
00:00:09,760 --> 00:00:12,962
So, Patrick, did you take the high road
```

Now, i tried to put the content of a subtitle file in an array, like this:

```
$f = fopen($file, 'rb');
$read = fread($f, filesize($file));
fclose($f);
$array = explode("\n",$read);
```

With this code:

```
$array = array_filter($array,'trim');
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(preg_match('/\d+/',$value)) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
$array = array_values($array);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

i get:

```
  Array
(
[0] => All right, guys, let's get to it.
[1] => What's that button?
[2] => It's something designed
[3] => to help you get healthy.
[4] => Just ignore it.
[5] => So, Patrick, did you take the high road
[6] => and congratulate Wendy on that promotion
[7] => that you were supposed to get?
[8] => Yes, I did. I even bought her flowers.
[9] => Liar!
 )
```

which is not ok because

```
 It's something designed
 to help you get healthy.
```

should be a in a single element of the array.

I've also tried to match everything between( example ) :

```
1
00:00:00,984 --> 00:00:03,503
```

and

```
2
00:00:03,587 --> 00:00:04,821
```

with:

```
(\d+\n)([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9],\d+ --> [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9],\d+\n).*\n
```

but it doesn't work and i'm out of ideas.

What i'm tring to output:

```
Array
(
[0] => All right, guys, let's get to it.
[1] => What's that button?
[2] => It's something designed to help you get healthy.
[3] => Just ignore it.
[4] => So, Patrick, did you take the high road
[5] => and congratulate Wendy on that promotion that you were supposed to get?
[6] => Yes, I did. I even bought her flowers.
[7] => Liar!
 )
 echo count($array); //for the previous array , should echo 8
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the multiline modifier in PCRE to handle the embedded newlines after reading in the file; and then match lines not starting with a number/digit to get what you want:

```
$file = "./subtitles.txt";
$content = file_get_contents($file);

$blocks = preg_split('/^\s*$/m', $content);
// var_export($blocks);

$subtitles = array();
for ($i=0; $i < count($blocks); $i++) {
    $lines = explode("\n", $blocks[$i]);
    $matches = preg_grep("/^[^\d]/", $lines);
    array_push($subtitles, implode(' ', $matches));
}

print_r($subtitles);
```

Which gives you the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => All right, guys, let's get to it.
    [1] => What's that button?
    [2] => It's something designed to help you get healthy.
    [3] => Just ignore it.
    [4] => So, Patrick, did you take the high road
)
```

Comment: That's a clean way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a mock up:

```
$array = array(1, '00', 'one', 2, '00', 'two', 'abc', 3, '00', 'three', 4, '00', 'four', 'five', 5, '00', 'six', 6, '00', 'seven');

$string_last = 0; // keep track when last element was string
$string_array = array(); // new array to add elements I want to keep
$ii = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(preg_match('/^\d+/',$value)) { // check if first character in line is a digit
        $string_last = 0; // if so, then last element is not string, go to next line
    }

    // we have string line
    else {
      if ( !$string_last ) { $ii++; } // if last element was not a string, increment index
      else { $string_array[$ii] .= ' '; } // ...otherwise add a space
      $string_array[$ii] .= $value;
      $string_last = 1;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($string_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Rather than unsetting elements I don't want I'm adding the elements I do want to a new array. That way I can merge consecutive string elements into one element in my new array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, by using library https://github.com/mantas-done/subtitles

```
$subtitles = Subtitles::load('subtitles.srt');
$blocks = $subtitles->getInternalFormat();
$array = [];
foreach ($blocks as $block) {
    $array[] = implode(' ', $block['lines']);
}

print_r($array);
```